# Public connection to GeoServer blocked on Amazon EC2 Instance

Tags: amazon-ec2, firewall, geoserver

I'm running GeoServer 2.7.2 on Windows 2012 server in Amazon EC2 instance. I can't connect to public ip address using http://x.x.x.x:8080/geoserver/web/.

I can remote into the server using RDP and connect using http://localhost:8080/geoserver/web/ just fine. But it will not connect using the public ip address.

I added port 8080 to the security group and even tried allowing all traffic to and out from the server. I made sure that the security group is assigned to the instance.

What am I missing? what else can I try to fix this problem?

Thanks

Comment: From CMD, what is the output of `netstat -na | findstr 8080`? Is windows built-in firewall configured to allow 8080?

Comment: Turned out it was windows firewall that's blocking it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We had the same problem on an AWS Linux box. We corrected it by assigning a [elastic IP](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/elastic-ip-addresses-eip.html) to the instance and then we could access it via the Elastic IP.

Before doing that, you can do one more test for configuration issue by trying the public DNS for the instance: ec2-**{IP}**.compute-1.amazonaws.com:8080/geoserver/web/

Hope this helps you.